# С# таймер и пауза

Tags: c#

Помогите мне нужно когда прогрес бар доходит до значения `500` из `1000`, чтобы он приостановился на 2 секунды.

P.S команда `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)` не работает.
Исходный код с ней:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LOL
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
            progressBar1.Step = 10;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Increment(+10);
            if (progressBar1.Value == 500) ;
            {
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var value = progressBar1.Value += 10;

  if (value == 500)
    timer1.Interval = 2000;
  else if (value == 510)
    timer1.Interval = 500;
}
```

А вообще, прогрессбары не для этого предназначены. И таймеры - тоже.